# $ mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 Enter password: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

Tags: mysql, localhost, cygwin

I am just a beginner to the programming world. I spent more than 14 hours making dozens of changes suggested in various answers on this site, but unsuccessful. Can some one help me?

I installed MySQL thru Cygwin.

I do not see my.cnf file, but do have 4 files, my-small.cnf to my-huge.cnf files, in `C:\cygwin64\usr\share\mysql.`

```
$ which mysql
/usr/bin/mysql.
```

And, have my-small.cnf, but no `binding-localhost` entry

```
[client]
 #password       = your_password
 host            = 127.0.0.1
 port            = 3306
 socket          = /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
```

If I enter first line, it prompts for password, but, the prompt does not accept any password nor move. If I enter anything, it will display error message.

```
$ mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1
Enter password:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

OR, if I enter

```
$ mysql -u root -p -h localhost
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysql.sock' (2)
```

OR, for alias entry

```
$ mysql start
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

Comment: How about 'mysql -u root' or 'mysql -u root -p root'?

Comment: Hi Dylan: The first option gave straight error. And, the second one prompted for the password; but neither accepted any nor moved the cursor

Comment: After "mysql -u root -p -h localhost" you can check the log of mysql to see what happens.

Comment: Hi Dylan: Can you please guide me how can I do it?

Comment: Try "ls /var/log/mysql*.log" to see if you can find anything

Comment: $ ls /var/log/mysql*.log*
ls: cannot access /var/log/mysql*.log*: No such file or directory

Comment: Then I don't know what is ur log position. you need to find by yourself.

Comment: Is the MySQL server running?

Comment: I entered    # /etc/init.d/mysql status    and it did not display any message.

Comment: Did you have the `#` as the first line when you ran it? That'd be a comment, not a command.

Comment: Hello AIG: I did not. I think the best option is to uninstall and follow the steps again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please forgive me for using ELI5 Method for Explaining steps:

> It may be a good idea to UNINSTALL and RE-INSTALL:

IF you have Completed the UN-INSTALLATION, then:

Make sure that your Cygwin Shell is CLOSED

Using Cygwin **setup-x86_64** (OR, setup-x86.exe, as appropriate for your system) start installation

Search in the top-left window and find:

```
mysql

mysqld
```

Proceed to Install and ACCEPT
its **dependencies** (RECOMMENDED)

Once the installation is FINISHED

START Cygwin Shell

For Starting MySQL DATABASE setup:

```
$ mysql_install_db
```

IF Firewall alert: (Choose appropriate)

For Running MySQL SERVER:

```
$ mysqld_safe &
```

IF Firewall alert: (Choose appropriate)

For Starting MySQL Installation:

```
$ mysql_secure_installation
```

IF Firewall alert: (Choose appropriate)

> Answering Questions:

root password: (Just **enter**, if you do not want)

remove anonymous users: **y**

disallow root login remotely: **y** (For the time being)

remove test database and access to it: **y**

reload privilege tables now: **y**

Now Start MySQL SERVER:

```
$ mysqld_safe
```

Leave this window OPEN and you can MINIMIZE it if you want, and start another window using **Alt+F2** OR using mouse by pointing to the top blue bar of the Cygwin Terminal (Window), then Right-click, and Click New

For Starting MYSQL DATABASE, in NEW Window:

yourPC@PCuser ~/usr/sbin

> (REPLACE **yourPC** & **PCuser** with the names you SEE on the Cygwin
>   Terminal)

```
$ mysql -u root -h localhost

mysql> \h
```

(You can read all the help)

```
mysql> \q
```

(For quitting mysql)

For Shutting Down MySQL SERVER

yourPC@PCuser ~/usr/sbin

(REPLACE **yourPC** & **PCuser** with the NAMES you see on the Cygwin Terminal)

```
$mysqladmin shutdown
```

IF the above does NOT shutdown, then:

```
$ mysqladmin -u root shutdown
```

Comment: I would like to upvote this answer, but it's so very...well, technically-written. I followed it, and it solved my problem, but it was kind of painful. Then again, you apologized in advance. And then again again, if you knew in advance it was going to be difficult, couldn't you have written it a bit more nicely? Thanks, in any case. :)